# How to print index and element of an Array in JS and C++?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, frontend

i want to print index and its element side by side in JS and C++.
like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
[ {0 : 1},
{1 : 2},
{2 : 3},
{3 : 4},
{4 : 5} ]
```

I have done like this, but not able to

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let obj = {};
  let emptArr = [];
  obj.i = arr[i];
  emptArr.push(obj);
  console.log(emptArr);
}
```

Comment: `i` is a variable (not the name of a property key) so it needs to be placed in square brackets. `obj[i] = arr[i];`

Comment: Also he creates a new array each time

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a new array each time

Here is how to store the object with the index as the key string. You cannot have a numeric key

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const newArr = arr.map((val,i) => ({[i]:val}));
console.log(newArr);
```

Here is your code fixed

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const emptArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[i] = arr[i];
  emptArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(emptArr);
```

Comment: Not the output the OP is after. `(i,val)` should be `(val, i)`

Comment: I added your missing semi-colons :)

Comment: @Andy at the same time I added his fixed code AND added semicolons ;)

Answer (score -1):

here is with map

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

const newArr = arr.map((value, index) => {
  return {
    [index]: value
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```